# Tool to log all incoming, outgoing traffic, apache server load etc

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

What's the best tool for generating server stats reports and a live monitoring? It feels like Webalizer got a bit behind.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using the module that comes with apache, it has lots of information (pages being accessed, memory being used per process and so forth) and is pretty usefull.

Make sure you have `mod_status.so` loaded within your apache modules then look for/add the above to your httpd.conf:

```
# Uncomment the following lines to enable mod_status support:
#
ExtendedStatus On

<Location /server-status>
SetHandler server-status

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from YOUR_IP_HERE
</Location>
```

To access it use http://YourServerIp/server-status

Comment: great thing.. just installed collectd which polls this information, too :)

Comment: great :), by the way you should also take a look at mod_backdoor http://people.apache.org/~trawick/ it is a nice addition to server-status in case you can't really browse your server on the default port.